# Shiny tutorial app does not render the histogram (show gray background) - using IE11

Tags: r, shiny

I am running a test shiny app and using IE 11 as the browser.  I get following error:
    Listening on 127.0.0.1:5679
    Error in serverFuncSource(): server.R returned an object of unexpected 
    type: list

The code for this application is public at the shiny website (shinydotrstudiodotcom/tutorial/lesson1/)

[image: This is how the app shows up]

Comment: Sounds like you've entered the sample code incorrectly. I would try again.

Comment: Indeed the case. Thank you. Apologies for the trouble. Thought must be an IE 11 issue.